# Inverted logic in Django ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I've got a model in Django with a `public` boolean field that controls whether the entry is public or private.

In the form, however, I should show an inverted logic: a checkbox for the `private` setting.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    private = forms.BooleanField(label="Make this entry private")

    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
```

How should I go from here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a **custom form field** that takes a boolean and flips it. The model's `public` field stays the same, but the form would use this new field to show the opposite, `private` value.

`prepare_value` flips the model's value to display the opposite on the form. `to_python` takes any incoming value from a submitted form and flips it in preparation for being saved to the model.

```
class OppositeBooleanField(BooleanField):
    def prepare_value(self, value):
        return not value  # toggle the value when loaded from the model

    def to_python(self, value):
        value = super(OppositeBooleanField, self).to_python(value)
        return not value  # toggle the incoming value from form submission


class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    public = OppositeBooleanField(label='Make this entry private', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

[**Updated answer**. The previous answer only handled saving a toggled form value, not displaying it properly when the value already existed.]

Comment: Eeeeh this is kinda bad. if you change clean method to return opposite value, then this opposite value will also be saved when you call modelform save.

Comment: That's precisely the goal, to get the opposite value. This method seemed the easiest to implement.

Comment: I understood, from his message, that he wants to show the opposite value, not keep/save it.

Comment: @Odif maybe we were both half right. My previous answer didn't work when *showing* the value. Thank you for pointing that out! I updated the answer to handle saving *and* displaying.

Answer (score 0):

You also have the option of displaying "private" in the template while keeping the django modelform field itself "public"

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    public = forms.BooleanField(label="Make this entry private")

    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
```

HTML template:

```
<form>
    <p>Private: {{ form.public }}</p>
</form>
```

Of course, in this case, you would need to reverse the user input once the form has been submitted to correct for the toggle.